# How to convert PySpark Word2Vec model and load it how gensim Word2Vec model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark, cluster-analysis, word2vec

I've generated a PySpark Word2Vec model and save it like:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import Word2Vec

w2v = Word2Vec(minCount = 1000, seed=42, inputCol="item_name", outputCol="features")
model = w2v.fit(sample)
model.save('w2v_pyspark')
```

Why i use PySpark W2V? Because i collected my sample from the *Hive* table and it s very huge sample, thats why i didn't transformed spark dataframe to pandas dataframe. So why i need *gensim*? Because i want to make beautiful visualisation. I need to cluster my word2vec model and visualise it, but pyspark functions haven't got so much functions and i can't use TensorBoard. So i tried to load model by gensim and it's didn't work, because no test data

```
from gensim.test.utils import datapath
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors

gensim_model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(datapath('w2v_pyspark'), binary=False)

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:u'/data/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gensim/test/test_data/w2v_pyspark'
```

I put my data from pyspark model to this path and it also didn't work. How can i solve this problem?
Also, if you know some ideas about how to cluster and visualise by PySpark, you are welcome!